# Inject EntityManager in an EventSubscriberInterface

Tags: symfony

I've done an EventSubscriber, but I need to use EntityManager in. I've filled the services.yml like this:

```
app.subscriber.tube_dynamic_field:
    class: AppBundle\Form\EventListener\TubeDynamicFieldSubscriber
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

I try to use it in the EventSubscriber like this:

```
class TubeDynamicFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    ...
}
```

Finally I use the EventSubscriber in a FormType like this:

```
class TubeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $dynamicFieldSubscriber;

    public function __construct(TubeDynamicFieldSubscriber $subscriber)
    {
        $this->dynamicFieldSubscriber = $suscriber;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->dynamicFieldSubscriber);
    }

...
}
```

But I've an error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\TubeType::__construct()
must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\EventListener
\TubeDynamicFieldSubscriber, none given
```

I've try to use it: `$builder->addEventSubscriber(new TubeDynamicFieldSuscriber())` but I've again an error: it don't recover the EntityManager.

If you know how I can inject the EntityManager in the EventSubscriber :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you include the classnames in your code snippets?

Comment: in order to respect the SOLID principle, you should "program to an interface, not a implementation" : I would recommend to change your FormType constructor : `public function __construct(EventSubscriberInterface $suscriber)
{
    $this->dynamicField = $suscriber;
}` so your class is not tightly coupled to your subscriber, and you can easily swap to an other subscriber

Comment: I've edited my message and include classnames.
Okay, for the SOLID principe, I go read it. I just start with Symfony and PHP. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your code snippets are not very clear, if your form type has dependencies, it needs to be registered in the service container so that Symfony (and the form factory) know how to construct it.

```
services:
    my_form_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\TubeType
        arguments:  ["@my_event_subscriber"]
        tags: [{ name: form.type }]
```

However, a better way of doing this is probably to inject the entity manager in the form type:

```
services:
    my_form_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\TubeType
        arguments:  ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags: [{ name: form.type }]
```

That way, in your code, you can just do:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new TubeDynamicFieldSuscriber($this->manager));
```

Comment: I think the second way is worse than the first. The best way is clearly to register your TubeType class as a service, give an alias to the tag (the same than the returned value of your TubeType:getName() method. Then, load this form with its alias : `$form = $this->createForm('app.forms.tube_type', new Tube());` see http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Comment: Form type aliases are deprecated in Symfony 2.8 and removed in Symfony 3.

Comment: then just load it as a standard service, `$form = $this->createForm($this->container->get('app.forms.tube_type'), new Tube());`

Comment: @Van - Don't take this the wrong way but you might want to learn a bit about Symfony before trying to help.  You are just confusing things.

Comment: @Cerad What am I confusing ? Please tell me, this would help me.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks a lot, It's work. But just a question, why we need to inject it in the FormType and we can't inject it on the fly with service directly in the Subscriber ?

Comment: Mostly because your subscriber has a dependency too. You could remove the dependency from the subscriber constructor, and instanciate that dependency inside the constructor method but this would violate the Dependency Inversion principle (one of the SOLID principle, again). And you want to inject the service from the services container, not instanciate a new one.

Comment: @VaN, the preferred way to pass the type is by passing the classname of the form type. If this form type was defined as a service and tagged with the `form.type` tag, the form factory will retrieve it from the service container itself.